# Error while using INDEX+MATCH in VBA (based on Excel formula)?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get content of mapping table based on 2 criteria.

Find below the formula I would like to convert

```
=INDEX(MappingTables!Y2:Y19;MATCH(1;(MappingTables!V2:V100=AE2)*(MappingTables!W2:W100=Y2);0))
```

Find below the current VBA code I'm using (where `RANGE` are constants) :

```
res = Application.Index(mappingTables.Range(RANGE1), Application.Match(1, (mappingTables.Range(RANGE2) = criteria1) * (mappingTables.Range(RANGE3) = criteria2), 0))
```

However, I'm getting below error

> Unidentified error detected. Process terminated.

Can you please help me to understand where is the issue ?

Thank you,

Regards,

Comment: The issue is in Excel. No user level code should cause it to crash.

Comment: Of course ahah. Maybe it is not possible and should I use `Application.Evaluation` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A construct like `(mappingTables.Range(RANGE2) = criteria1) * (mappingTables.Range(RANGE3) = criteria2)` does not work in VBA, you can only do this with an array of data in formulas.

This `mappingTables.Range(RANGE3)` is an array of values and VBA cannot compare entire arrays without looping, nor can it multiply entire arrays without looping.

In VBA you would have to loop through that data to calulate the result for each data point in the array.

To avoid that I recommend to use `Evaluate` and a formula:

```
res = Evaluate("=INDEX(MappingTables!Y2:Y19,MATCH(1,(MappingTables!V2:V100=AE2)*(MappingTables!W2:W100=Y2),0))")
```

or better

```
res = Evaluate("=INDEX(MappingTables!" & RANGE1 & ",MATCH(1,(MappingTables!" & RANGE2 & "=" & Criteria1 & ")*(MappingTables!" & RANGE2 & "=" & Criteria2 & "),0))")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. For the moment, this is returning `#VALUE!` so I guess there is an issue in the arguments provided to the formula. `Criteria1` and `Criteria2` should not be put between `" "` ? to avoid to have something like `...=jos dos)*(...` where `jos dos` is `Criteria1` ?

Comment: @Royce Well then you need to set your criteria like `Criteria1 = """jos dos"""` so the `"` are included for text criteria. The criteria could alse be numeric that is why I didn't include the quotes in the formula directly but if you have always text criteria include them in the formula like `RANGE2 & "=""" & Criteria1 & """)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback. This is strange, the formula is working in a cell (I retrieve it with Debug.Print) but still returning  `#VALUE!` with `Evaluate` function. Length of the formula cannot impact the result ? My formula contains 97 chars.

Comment: @Royce wait, replace the `;` in the formula with `,` the evaluate function only accepts `,` as delimiter (default US english).